# Entity Framework error: The object 'PK_dbo.User' is dependent on column 'Id'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I pass the [ASP.NET MVC 5 tutorial](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-site-with-sql-database/) and want to rewrite existing app to mvc 5.
Let's say I have 2 tables - `Users` and `Categories` and they are connect on `UserID`.

In mvc5 we can connect authentification model to our db, so I updated sample `User` model with

```
public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
```

also in `Category` model I added

```
public int UserID { get; set; }
public User User { get; set; }
```

I worked for me in mvc3/ef4. But when I do migration I am getting error:

> The object 'PK_dbo.User' is dependent on column 'Id'.
>   ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Id failed because one or more objects access this column.

Here are my models:

User (1 to 1 from sample project + link to categories)

```
public class User : IUser
{
    public User()
        : this(String.Empty)
    {
    }

    public User(string userName)
    {
        UserName = userName;
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Category model

```
public class Category
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int ParentID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    //....
}
```

context

```
public class BackendDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserSecret> Secrets { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserLogin> UserLogins { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }

    protected override DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry, IDictionary<object, object> items)
    {
       //
    }
}
```

Comment: If a user's `Id` property is a string, how will you be able to refer to it with an `int UserID` property in a different class?

Comment: i am idiot! thank you!

Comment: please add it as answer, so i be able to accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elaborating from the comments:

Your `User` class has a `string` key property. The category's `UserID` property needs to have the same type. Since they're not, I'm guessing that EF is attempting to modify the `ID` column to match `UserID`'s type, which is not supposed to work.

However, an added note:

You are setting your user IDs via

```
Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

but the natural type for storing that is `Guid` (`uniqueidentifier` in SQL Server). You could change both the user's `ID` property and the category's `UserID` property to that.